# All you need to know to properly handle date and time

Tags: date, time

I've found myself several times immerse in the task of handling dates and times, and I realize that there are lots of concepts involved that I don't really grasp (formats, time zones, calendars, etc). Because of that, I would like to ask you about resources (books, posts, etc) that allow me to get all the needed knowledge to properly face this task.

Thanks!

Comment: In [this link](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/externalresources/) you can find lots of useful resources. The first video (*Date and Time Odds, Ends and Oddities*) is very interesting. But "all the needed knowledge" is too broad, because there's *a lot* to learn about it. For timezones, a good look in [tz mail list](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/) is interesting, to know all the problems faced by people trying to maintain the timezone database. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start is looking for "Falsehood" articles.

E.g.:

- http://www.creativedeletion.com/2015/01/28/falsehoods-programmers-date-time-zones.html
- http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time (and the associated discussion on Hacker News: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4128208)

And then the rest is mostly about picking the right library for your programming language(s) that handles those cases correctly (unless it is your **job** to roll your own library).

Comment: Also if you need to know the basic concepts i.e what is UTC and what is a timezone this is a good quick overview http://statoids.com/tconcept.html